# Django OAuth2 migrate key error

Tags: django, migrate, syncdb

Welcome, when i'm try to syncdb --migarte it gives me an error:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --migrate
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Migrating...
Running migrations for oauth2:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__add_field_client_name.
 > oauth2:0002_auto__chg_field_client_user
KeyError: u'url'
```

What's wrong?
edit: i'n not using oauth anywhere yet.

Comment: Could you give a link to the package?

Comment: @sneawo, what package? Oauth2?